# Apache: workers are still raising

Tags: apache

I have to reboot my web server regulary because it fails to handle new apache requests. Please check the graph - workers are still raising. But I am not able to figure out why? What can cause this problem?

Feel free to check my monitorix stats: http://jsemtu.cz/monitorix/

[image]

My mpm_prefork:

```
StartServers             5
MinSpareServers       10
MaxSpareServers      30
MaxRequestWorkers     70
ServerLimit   70
MaxClients  70
MaxConnectionsPerChild   180
```

Comment: If you provide your apache config will be easy to help you.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, thank you, I added my mpm_prefork config to first post.

Comment: Have you consider to set `MaxConnectionsPerChild 0`. Or at least 5000, 10000. 180 looks for me too small. Most of the time your server kill and spawn new child processes.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to set value "0" and will monitor it.

Comment: Hello @RomeoNinov, I would like to tell you that the problem was not resolved by this change. Is possible that there is any script with memory leak? I really don't know how can I debug it.

Comment: New graph here: https://1iq.cz/img/V2r2A/ESGj4.png

Comment: Can you enable the extended status endpoint (beware of security) https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html  and check the url that stay in working state.

Comment: Could you check in your apache status page if there are any processes hanging the the "G" status?

Comment: use gdb/pstack to show what your processes are actually doing. Anything else is guessing.